# How to check for negative numbers sent to smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, truffle

I want my contract not to accept negative values being added to it's balance, so I thought I'd add a require value > 0. It seams though as the value sent with the payable function is unsigned and therefore always a positive number. Meaning if you send -1 ether it is accepted and adds about 1 ether instead.

How do I make sure no negative numbers can be sent?

```
function () external payable {
  require(msg.value > 0); 
  require(msg.data.length == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to send a negative value in EVM. So `msg.value` is always non-negative. You don't need to check that.

Comment: Ah! Gotcha! So the test case in remix when I send -1 eth and it gets added to the balance can never happen in a real situation on the mainnet?

Comment: Exactly, it is not a valid opcode, Ethereum Virtual Machine won't execute it. @Adremalin